# How to use SqlAlchemy on multithreading pool

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I'm having a pretty big problem with using sqlalchemy in multithreading
for example this is my sqlalchemy connection

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

import config

engine: Engine = create_engine(config.DATABASE_URL, echo=False, pool_size=30, max_overflow=0)
SessionLocal = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                           autoflush=False,
                                           bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()


def get_database():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

This is my used in a service

```
class ProductService:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """
        :return None
        """
        self.db = next(get_database())
```

and here i use this service in multithreading

```
class ProductEmbedding(nn.Module):
    """
    :return None
    """
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(ProductEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.input_size: int = 10000  # input size used for each embed
        self.embedding_dim: int = 64  # embedding size
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.input_size, self.embedding_dim)
        self.storage_path: str = './storage/fasttext_storage/'
        self.attribute_key_loaded_model = fasttext.load_model(f'{self.storage_path}key_model.bin')
        self.attribute_value_loaded_model = fasttext.load_model(f'{self.storage_path}value_model.bin')
    
    def process_batch(
            self,
            offset: int,
            limit: int,
            product_service: ProductService,
    ):
        products = product_service.get_all(limit=limit, offset=offset)
        
        for product in products:
            print(f"[SUCCESS_EMBED]: Embed created for product {product.id} and client {product.clientId}")
            self.forward(product=product, product_service=product_service)
            
    def invoke(self) -> None:
        product_service: ProductService = ProductService()
        
        total_products: int = product_service.count_products()
        
        num_threads = 4  # Adjust this to the number of threads you want
        
        # Calculate the batch size for each thread
        batch_size = total_products // num_threads
        
        threads = []
        
        for i in range(num_threads):
            offset = i * batch_size
            limit = batch_size if i < num_threads - 1 else total_products - offset
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process_batch, args=(offset, limit, product_service))
            threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()
        
        # Wait for all threads to complete
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

The problem is that if I start another thread, my connection disappears.
How can I fix this? Should I move the service directly as a separate thread or?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea, you can't share the same session (which encapsulates an actively in-use connection) across multiple threads because that's not thread-safe. See [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594689/python-thread-sqlalchemy), [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769299/is-connection-pool-in-sqlalchemy-thread-safe), and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297404/multi-threaded-use-of-sqlalchemy).